# How to check if a Java source file is valid (has no errors)?

Tags: java, validation, javaparser

In my code I open my **file.java** and parse him with [JavaParser](https://code.google.com/p/javaparser/wiki/UsingThisParser).

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(".../file.java");

        CompilationUnit cu;

        try {
            // parse the file
            cu = JavaParser.parse(in);
        } finally {
            in.close();
        }

........
```

**file.java**:

```
public class File{

     public void ownMethod(){...}

     public static void main(String[] args){

          ownMethod(5); //Note the extra parameter

     }
}
```

In file.java there is an error: The method `main` calls the method `ownMethod` with one parameter, but `ownMethod` expects 0 parameters. JavaParser doesn't detect this error and parses file.java with this error. How can I know (in my code) whether file.java has no errors? Is it posible without using a java compiler?

Comment: class needs to be written using a lowercase c. :)

Comment: No problem, its those small things you never see yourself. :)

Comment: This is possible with the Eclipse JDT https://eclipse.org/jdt/ . Of course, this *is* a Java Compiler in some sense, but it can be deployed as a bunch of JARs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it posible without using java compiler?

No. Any solution, which your (re?)invent, will lead you to yet-another-one compiler. Parse & validate for errors is an essential part of compiler's job.

Comment: Well IDE can verify that without explicitly compiling it (yes, it actually DOES compile it, but in background and you never see it, so that counts I guess)

Comment: @MightyPork Explicitly or implicitly, it does compile it. So ursa's point stands.

Comment: I agree: there are many things for which you basically need a compiler. However we are planning to build some validation in JavaParser itself in the future, so we can check if the AST is valid. For a full validation we would also need to use JavaSymbolSolver, which resolve types and method calls. It basically re-implement a lot of stuff you find in a compiler.